# How to achive Repository layer test cases with isolation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, junit5

**This is my repository layer test cases I am written**

```
@DataJpaTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles(TestConstant.TEST_PROFILE)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
class FriendRequestDboRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired private FriendRequestRepository friendRequestRepository;

   private static final FriendRequestDbo REQUEST = createFriendRequest();

    private static FriendRequestDbo createFriendRequest() {
        final var friendRequestDbo = new FriendRequestDbo();
        friendRequestDbo.setSenderId(1);
        friendRequestDbo.setReceiverId(2);
        friendRequestDbo.setStatus(FriendRequestStatus.PENDING);
        friendRequestDbo.setMessage("Hello");
        return friendRequestDbo;
    }

    @Test
    void findBySenderIdAndReceiverIdOrderByIdDesc() {
        friendRequestRepository.save(REQUEST);
        final var result =
                friendRequestRepository.findFirstBySenderIdAndReceiverIdOrderByIdDesc(
                        REQUEST.getSenderId(), REQUEST.getReceiverId());
        assertTrue(result.isPresent());
        assertEquals(REQUEST.getStatus(), result.get().getStatus());
    }

    @Test
    void findByReceiverIdAndSenderIdOrderByIdDesc() {
        friendRequestRepository.save(REQUEST);
        final var result =
                friendRequestRepository.findFirstByReceiverIdAndSenderIdOrderByIdDesc(
                        REQUEST.getReceiverId(), REQUEST.getSenderId());
        assertTrue(result.isPresent());
        assertEquals(REQUEST.getStatus(), result.get().getStatus());
    }

    @Test
    void findByIdAndStatus() {
        friendRequestRepository.save(REQUEST);
        final var result = friendRequestRepository.findByIdAndStatus(REQUEST.getId(), FriendRequestStatus.PENDING);
        assertTrue(result.isPresent());
        assertEquals(REQUEST.getStatus(), result.get().getStatus());
    }
```

**this is my entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "friend_request")
public class FriendRequestDbo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private long senderId;

    private long receiverId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private FriendRequestStatus status;

    private String message;

    public FriendRequestDbo() {}

    public FriendRequestDbo(
            int id, long senderId, long receiverId, FriendRequestStatus status, String message) {
        this.id = id;
        this.senderId = senderId;
        this.receiverId = receiverId;
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getSenderId() {
        return senderId;
    }

    public void setSenderId(long senderId) {
        this.senderId = senderId;
    }

    public long getReceiverId() {
        return receiverId;
    }

    public void setReceiverId(long receiverId) {
        this.receiverId = receiverId;
    }

    public FriendRequestStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(FriendRequestStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

## if my test cases are isolated or not?

## If it's not how to write repository layer test cases with isolation

**My main problem is when I run all the test cases my primary key was incremented and it's infected on other test cases**

-> Please provide me with a proper solution to this problem.